# Field 'xxx' expected a number but got <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField>

Tags: django

Here is my code:
In forms.py

```
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ("title","business_partner","transaction")
        widgets = {
            'transaction': forms.NumberInput()
        }
```

In views.py

```
def uploadpdf(request,pk):
    project_form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
    
    if project_form.is_valid() and request.FILES:
        project_form.instance.user = request.user
        
        project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
        project.title = project_form['title']
        project.business_partner = project_form['business_partner']
        project.transaction = project_form['transaction']
        project.save()
        
        project = Project.objects.get(id=pk)
        file_path = None
        for file in request.FILES:
            file = request.FILES[file]
            pdf_file = PDFFile(file=file, filename=file.name)
            pdf_file.project = project
            pdf_file.save()
            if PRODUCTION:
                file_path = HOST_NAME +'/'+  str(pdf_file.file)
            else:
                file_path = HOST_NAME +'/media/'+  str(pdf_file.file)
        resp = HttpResponse(f'{{"message": "Uploaded successfully...", "id": "{project.id}","url":"{file_path}","title": "{project.title}"}}')
        resp.status_code = 200
        resp.content_type = "application/json"
        return resp
    else:
        return reverse("dashboard:homepage")
```

When I run this, it says like "TypeError: Field 'transaction' expected a number but got <django.forms.boundfield.BoundField object at 0x000001A803935250>."

Looking forward to hearing a good solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the cleaned_data attribute of the form instead of the field itself like so:

```
project.transaction = project_form.cleaned_data['transaction']
```

Edit: Note that you should have to do the same for the other fields.

Comment: Thanks, It has solved.